# Pig Latin Different configurations for different stages of script

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig script which runs multiple map reduce jobs. (Ex: 'group by' and 'order by' which will be executed as 2 different map reduce jobs)
Is there a way to specify different map reduce configuration options for different stages instead of specifying them for the whole script (Ex: different values for mapred.min.split.size for different stages)?

Answer (score 0):

Pig is DAG, which execute steps one by one. You can give MR configs to whole pig script. There is no such option to tune each step individually in Pig